# Empty handle cannot be dereferenced in calling QuantLib::Instrument NPV() method

Tags: inheritance, this, handle, quantlib

**The setup**

First of all, `using namespace QuantLib` to shorten the code snippets.

[`ZeroCouponBond`](http://quantlib.org/reference/class_quant_lib_1_1_zero_coupon_bond.html) inherits from [`Instrument`](http://quantlib.org/reference/class_quant_lib_1_1_instrument.html). `ZeroCouponBondWrapper` inherits from `ZeroCouponBond`: its purpose is just to set some default values for constructor arguments and, overall, to embed the setting of a pricing engine straight from a yield curve:

```
class ZeroCouponBondWrapper :
    public ZeroCouponBond
{
public:
    ZeroCouponBondWrapper(Real faceAmount,
        const Date& maturityDate,
        const boost::shared_ptr< YieldTermStructure >& yieldTermStructure,
        Real redemption);
    virtual ~ZeroCouponBondWrapper();
};

ZeroCouponBondWrapper::ZeroCouponBondWrapper(Real faceAmount,
    const Date& maturityDate,
    const boost::shared_ptr< YieldTermStructure >& yieldTermStructure,
    Real redemption)
    : ZeroCouponBond(2, TARGET(), faceAmount, maturityDate, Following, redemption, Date())
{
    boost::shared_ptr< PricingEngine > discountingBondEngine(new DiscountingBondEngine(Handle< YieldTermStructure >(yieldTermStructure)));
    this->setPricingEngine(discountingBondEngine);
}
```

Now we have an object which is an `Instrument`, so it has a [`NPV()`](http://quantlib.org/reference/class_quant_lib_1_1_instrument.html#a4f791921f063f3ea19bd6efa9ceb4892) method. Let's define another class: `EquityProtectionCertificate` inherits from `ZeroCouponBondWrapper`. As you can see, it is also implemented in terms of an array of (shared pointers to) [`EuropeanOption`](http://quantlib.org/reference/class_quant_lib_1_1_european_option.html): `EuropeanOption` are objects of class `Instrument`, too... so they have a `NPV()` method.

```
class EquityProtectionCertificate :
    public ZeroCouponBondWrapper
{
public:
    EquityProtectionCertificate(...);
    ...
    double CalculateNPV();
private:
    std::vector< boost::shared_ptr< EuropeanOption >> europeanOptions_;
    ...
}
```

Its constructor implementation deals with `ZeroCouponBondWrapper` constructor:

```
EquityProtectionCertificate::EquityProtectionCertificate(Real x0,
    const boost::shared_ptr< YieldTermStructure >& dividendTS,
    const boost::shared_ptr< YieldTermStructure >& riskFreeTS,
    const boost::shared_ptr< BlackVolTermStructure >& blackVolTS,
    const Date& maturityDate,
    Real faceAmount,
    Real redemption,
    const boost::shared_ptr< YieldTermStructure >& yieldTermStructure,
    Real startingReferenceValue,
    Real protection,
    Real participation,
    Real cap)
    : ZeroCouponBondWrapper(faceAmount, maturityDate, yieldTermStructure, redemption),
    N_(faceAmount), S0_(x0)
{
    boost::shared_ptr< EuropeanOption > theFloor(new EuropeanOptionWrapper(Option::Call,
        startingReferenceValue,
        maturityDate,
        x0,
        riskFreeTS,
        dividendTS,
        blackVolTS));
    europeanOptions_.push_back(theFloor);
    boost::shared_ptr< EuropeanOption > theCap(new EuropeanOptionWrapper(Option::Call,
        startingReferenceValue * cap,
        maturityDate,
        x0,
        riskFreeTS,
        dividendTS,
        blackVolTS));
    europeanOptions_.push_back(theCap);
}
```

`EquityProtectionCertificate` doesn't override `NPV()` method; instead, it has its own `CalculateNPV()` which makes use of `NPV()`:

```
double EquityProtectionCertificate::CalculateNPV()
{
    double npv = 0.0;
    npv += this->NPV();
    npv += (europeanOptions_[0]->NPV() * N_ / S0_);
    npv -= (europeanOptions_[1]->NPV() * N_ / S0_);
    return npv;
}
```

(`N_` and `S0_` are just other private `double` variables).

**The problem**

When you call `this->NPV()` inside the constructor, it returns the proper value: this means that `setPricingEngine()` is properly called. However, when you call `this->NPV()` inside `CalculateNPV()`, it doesn't return any value: on the contrary, it returns an exception which says `empty Handle cannot be dereferenced`. Could you explain what's wrong with my use of `this->NPV()` and/or inheritance concepts?

Comment: May you also post the constructor of `EquityProtectionCertificate`?

Comment: Sure, Luigi... done.

Comment: Well, I hate to say that it works on my machine, but it works on my machine; at least the zero-coupon part, because I'm missing the code for your `EuropeanOptionWrapper` class.  Are you sure it's `this->NPV()` that raises the exception and not the calls to `NPV` on the options?

Comment: Hmm... Debug said that. Let me dig a bit more into this, I would hate to have written such endless manuscript just to cancel it due to problem inconsistency.

Comment: This said, since you're already storing the two options inside the certificate, it might be simpler if you stored the bond as well instead of inheriting from it...